# Spring Boot Registration Server(Eureka Server)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices

I am working on a Spring Boot Registration Server(Eureka Server).
Currently it is working with below configuration.

**Project Name:** registration-service
**Inside main method:** System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "registration-service");

**"yml file":**
   **file name:** registration-service
   **content:**

```
     eureka:
      instance:
        hostname: eureka-server
      server:
        enableSelfPreservation: false
      client:
        register-with-eureka: false
        fetch-registry: false
        serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/


    server:
      port: 2323   # HTTP (Tomcat) port




spring:
 application:
  name: eureka-server
```

With above configuration,application start running on 2323.
But if i change **spring.config.name**,it does not work,start giving connection refused exception.

1. why it is happening? even though this spring.config.name is no where used in yml file. Should it be necessarily same as project name? or it is specific to @EnableEurekaServer enabled spring boot application.
2. And in yml we have to write

spring:
 application:
  name: eureka-server

though in other spring boot application we give name of current project(here it should be registration-service).why we have to write here eureka-server? I know,I am missing something(or a lot of things).please help me in understanding the missing part.

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot by default looks for file application.yml. If u have different profiles in your application it can also look for application-{profilename}.yml. This is the default convention followed.

spring.config.name property is used to override this default behaviour. When u override this property with register-service then spring boot looks for a file register-service.yml and loads config from that.

So your eureka server url which is given in the register-service.yml file may not be available in the default application.yml file. Hence when u change the value Spring boot may not be avle to find the Eureka server url.

Keep the names unchanged, as much as possible. If u have config file as register-service.yml then keep the spring.config.name=register-service. If you change this value then u need to create the new file with config.name value and then add eureka configuration to that again.

Comment: and why in *.yml file we have to write spring:
 application:
  name: eureka-server. Though in other boot application, we write "name:(whatever name we have written in System.setProperty )"

Comment: In Eureka, default spring.application.name is used as the serviceId. Service id is a key to Identify any individual service inside a Eureka cluster. Inside Eureka the serviceId and metadata about the actual service is maintained as a key value pairs map. Any name you give as a Spring application is used as a unique identifier for your service in Eureka. As per my knowledge there is no name property in spring configuration available. You can go through the below link to find available ones. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html